# arithmetic and repetition in perl replacement text

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to print a number of '+' characters followed by a number of '-' characters, with the number of repetitions determined by some simple arithmetic. Can you tell me what's wrong with the following (this works without the attempt at division):

```
some-command | perl -pe 's/(\d+) (\d+)/ "+" x ($1 / 4) . "-" x ($2 / 4)/eg'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/` needs to be escaped. Try:

```
some-command | perl -pe 's/(\d+) (\d+)/ "+" x ($1\/4) . "-" x ($2\/4)/eg'
```

Another option is to use a different character than `/` for your regex:

```
some-command | perl -pe 's;(\d+) (\d+); "+" x ($1/4) . "-" x ($2/4);eg'
```